# WI-FI adapter not found , and Git repo not available to fix that?

Tags: wireless, hp

I have hp laptop and I can't connect to my WIFI show always `No Wi-Fi Adapter Found` , to fix that I don't have the git repository , I have fixed that issue previously , but I re-install of the OS in later time  ,

**rtlwifi_new** if this repository available with you please send me to get that, I can fix the issue

git clone -b extended https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git (currently not available  )

command  `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`

output

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
DeviceName: WLAN
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:831a]
Kernel modules: rtw_8821ce, 8821ce
```

Comment: What OS/release?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Larry Finger's `rtlwifi_new` git repo is not available.

He created a new `rtw88` repo.

https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88

For Ubuntu it is recommended to install using `dkms`. The `dkms.conf` file is available there.

Comment: when i try to `sudo modprobe -r  rtw8821ce`  but it show `Module rtw8821ce not found.`,    what should I do?

Comment: It is `rtw_8821ce`.